# TFS 2013, Code review assigned to me but I don't see it in my work items

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-code-review

Using TFS 2013 from Visual Studio 2012/2015, a developer requests a code review from me for a shelveset (I've seen their screenshot). However, the request never appears in my work items.

Any ideas why?

Also, same shelveset, I can view and comment using the web portal, but the portal has no "Send with Comments" button that I can see.

Should I be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can not search work items for code review because they in hidden category: https://hemantmahajan08.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/new-workitem-type-but-hidden-in-microsoft-tfs-2012/

You can find code review requests on My Work panel only: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs

Also you may try to remove code review work item types from hidden category, but I did not try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-categories